# Entity Framework Core naviagional property does not remain null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class with a linked class, as example imagine a Person with a Dog. It is mapped like this in the PersonDto:

```
public int? DogId { get; set; }
public virtual DogDto Dog { get; set; }
```

For many persons the DogId is null, but after I change something in Person and do a SaveChanges then entity framework insist that it should insert a blank entry.

My scenario is a lot bigger but simplified it could look like this:

```
var person = await _entities.Persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Ann")
            .Select(p => p).Include(p => p.Dog).First();
person.Name = "Bob";
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

Imagine now that Ann does not have a dog, and DogId should remain null.

The SQL Entity Framework Core does an INSERT like this:

```
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [Dogs] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, 0),
(@p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, 1)) AS i ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5], 
_Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5])
VALUES (i.[Col1], i.[Col2], i.[Col3], i.[Col4], i.[Col5])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;
```

What am I missing. Wouldn't int? be enough to allow it to be null?

Comment: Why are you including a dog while selecting? If you just need to change the name of person!

Comment: I have a lot of generic methods, so the get method gets the dog because other may want to do something with the dog.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at this (I could be wrong), and say the problem is probably stemming from trying to eager load (.Include(...)) a navigation property marked as virtual which means it's lazy loaded. You have to pick one. And since lazy loading is not turned on by default (because it causes weird side effects like this), unless you've opted into lazy loading, you shouldn't use the virtual keyword.

Comment: @AdamVincent you are completly right it is virtual. Thanks. I will try to work on a solution with that. Thanks

Comment: Are you using [Lazy loading proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading), i.e. has `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` configuration call somewhere in the code? Because if you do so, you wont' be able to remove `virtual` from the navigation property. Also can the issue be reproduced with your "simplified example"? Because if yes, then it's EF Core bug.

Comment: I'm with @IvanStoev in that the `virtual` keyword _should_ have no effect if lazy loading is not being used. I'm almost certain I've seen exactly that written in the documentation. But since removing the virtual keyword resolved the issue, there may be an oversight somewhere.

Comment: I work on the EF team and I cannot guess what could be going on. I would not expect virtual to have anything to do with it. But it is not super clear what the symptoms are, or if you have any additional configuration like owned entities. It should be ok to use eager loading and lazy loading together. I would like to make sure it is not a bug, but to investigate we need a project that reproduces the behavior. If you can provide that, please create an issue at https://GitHub.com/AspNet/EntityframeworkCore/issues/new. You can reference this thread in the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to post an answer in case any search ends here.

It was completly correct that virtual does not matter, and the issue was in some mapping between my Dto and domain layer where I, by mistake, attached a blank entry.